# Flush a pipe associated to an NSFileHandle

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilehandle

I am reading piped output from a console application via an NSFileHandle in Cocoa.  How can I flush the stream associated to that file handle.  If I could get a FILE* object from the NSFileHandle I could call fflush().  Is there a way around this?

Comment: You could try `fdopen()` followed by `fflush()` but I’m not sure pipes need to be flushed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the equivalent in `NSFileHandle` is [`-synchronizeFile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/synchronizeFile).

Comment: This results in an operation-not-supported exception if the underlying file handle is an NSPipe.

Comment: @EricapRhys is there an alternative solution to `synchronizeFile` for this case?